# Return error in the implementation of an interface using generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface defining a method like this :

```
public List<IA> myMethod();
```

with `IA` another interface.

In my implementation of the method I declare :

```
public List<A> myMethod() { /* Do something */ }
```

with `A` a class implementing `IA`.

However, Java (or eclipse) doesn't like it and forces me to have `List<IA>` in my implementation of `myMethod`. As `A` implements `IA`, I don't see why this casts an error.

So here are the questions :

- Why do I have this error ?
- Which is the best way to avoid it (knowing I do not have much liberty on the code) ?

Comment: could you be more specific about the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this error because it's unsafe from a type-safety point of view. Consider:

```
// Interface declaration
List<Fruit> myMethod();

// Implemented by...
public List<Banana> myMethod() {
    return new ArrayList<Banana>();
}

// Called as:
List<Fruit> fruit = foo.myMethod();
fruit.add(new Apple());
```

Do you really want to be able to add an `Apple` to an `ArrayList<Banana>`?

You can fix this by changing the declaration to

```
List<? extends IA> myMethod();
```

That will prevent calls from adding to the list (or setting values on it).

If you can't change the interface, you will *have* to return a `List<IA>` from your method, I'm afraid.

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for much more information.

Comment: OMG, it's Jon Skeet. Now nobody will see my answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Because the contract defined in `interface` says that `myMethod` must return a List of type `IA`.

As a thumb rule: **Base class reference can be used anywhere, when derived class object is required.** but vice-versa is NOT true. and that's the error.

To avoid these error: always follow the interface (contract) as it is.